# Is there a helper to display a comma separator if the value exists?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have the following helper:

```
def results(grade, percent, date)
  "#{grade} #{percent} , #{date}"
end
```

Basically I want my output to look like:

```
10 %, 12/12/2012
```

The above helper works fine if `grade`, `percent` and `date` exist.

However, there are other scenarios that needs to be handled. For example, if `grade` and `percent` are both empty, then I would get the following output:

```
,12/12/2012
```

If the `date` is empty then:

```
10 % ,
```

I could do a bunch of `if`/`else` statements and handle the above case, but I wondered if there is a smarter way to handle this?

In the above scenarios, I dont want the comma to be displayed.

Comment: Why are you passing percent as a parameter. Its always suppose to be '%'. Am I right..?

Comment: actually percernt would be replaced with units. it can be anything

Comment: What do you mean by `value`, `unit` and `date`? You only  have `grade`, `percent`, and `date`.

Comment: In other scenarios, you show how they are currently handled, but you do not show how you want them to be handled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first that came up in my head was to split it into an array. For the first part i would use `lstrip`to remove whitespaces before and after and then join with date.

```
def results(amount, unit, date)
  ["#{amount} #{unit}".lstrip , date].reject(&:blank?).join(', ')
end
```